# Hibernate: Loading List of Objects with Ancestor Types in Broad Class Hierarchy Efficiently

Tags: java, database, performance, hibernate, inheritance

Say there is a class `RootClass` from which all child classes C1, C2, ..., C20 inherit either directly or with a maximum of two other classes in between. These classes are stored with the use of hibernate in a relational database (currently MariaDB, although shouldn't matter). The inheritance is handled by using the single table strategy but with each child C1 to C20 storing its additional properties within secondary tables and the primary table containing a discriminator column.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PrimaryTable")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class RootClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Integer getId() {...}
    void setId(Integer id) {...}

    @Column(name = "genericval")
    String getSomeGenericValue() {...}
    void setSomeGenericValue(String v) {...}

    [...]
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("c1")
@SecondaryTable(name = "COneTable", pkJoinColumns = {@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
public class C1 extends RootClass {

    @Column(name = "specificval", table = "COneTable")
    String getValueSpecificToThisChildType() {...}
    void setValueSpecificToThisChildType(String v) {...}

    [...]
}

[...]
```

This design allows efficient queries for a particular symbol (a single join is required) and at the same time does not create a huge table with mostly empty cells (using simply a SINGLE_TABLE strategy with no secondary tables).

**The problem**: Another object stored in the database has a <s>collection of</s> map with `RootClass` instances as values (a mix of C1, ... C20, some of which may refer to further Cx instances), which are lazily fetched. Now when I try to iterate over all of those instances (required for some functionality), hibernate builds a query with a huge number of joins (>80) to retrieve the collection, resulting in a `java.sql.SQLException: Too many tables; MariaDB can only use 61 tables in a join`.

How can retrieve a collection of `RootClass` instances from the database, which may be of a number of types in a somewhat efficient manner? What do I have to change in my database design for this sort of inheritance model to work? Thanks!

**Update:** So apparently I also get an oddly large (too large) join when trying to retrieve an entity with `session.get(RootClass.class, 123)`, 123 being an ID of a particular entity. If I instead use `session.createQuery("from RootClass where id = :id").setParameter("id", 123).uniqueResult()` the resulting query is a lot smaller, with a fraction of the number of joins, and successful. Am yet to investigate whether this has something to do directly with the issue above.

Comment: How many classes extend the RootClass?

Comment: Directly extending RootClass are, in fact only two classes (say L1i and L1ii). One of these (L1ii) is then extended by 11 classes (L2i...L2xi), of which two (L2x and L2xi) each have two extending classes (L3i, L3ii and L3iii, L3iv). So the entire hierarchy, if seen as a tree, has 4 levels with 1, 2, 11 and 4 nodes per level and 14 leaf nodes.